# error in forward selection on large data set in R

Tags: r, performance, large-data

I'm trying to run forward selection on a large data set, which has 4000 observations and 4000 variables. However, I get the following error when I run the code

```
> regfit.fwd<-regsubsets(X986~.,data=train.fin, really.big=TRUE, method="forward")
Error in leaps.setup(x, y, wt = wt, nbest = nbest, nvmax = nvmax, force.in = force.in,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)
```

I don't have NAs in the data set, and I am trying to figure out what is causing the error.

Comment: Forward selection with that data is going to give you statistical garbage.

Comment: Would you recommend a different way for variable selection? Some suggeted fs, so I would like to know.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I'm considering lasso suggested here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8303/how-to-do-logistic-regression-subset-selection